# How to implement SSO using AWS Cognito Identity JS

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, jwt, single-sign-on, amazon-cognito

I have integrated AWS Cognito Identity JS into a custom UI with all sign in / forgot password / sign out functionality. But now i want to log in to the dashboard by logging in from a different domain and not from the domain where my website is hosted. I am using AWS Cognito but because of limited resources i am not able to find a feasible solution. In my domain where i have hosted my website i a able to login by setting all tokens onto local storage and if there is any object in local storage i am navigating my user to dashboard. My dashboard is a protected route.

Using SSO in React using AWS Cognito Identity JS

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.